# How to make Yahoo Finance stock quote an integer

Tags: python, yahoo, finance

I am trying to write a program that will run some valuation models and than return a judgment (int 1 - 10) on the inputted stock. I am struggling because the yahoo-finance module I am using to gather data (stock quotes) is not returned to me as an integer. I found a temporary solution by changing the stock quote to a float then to an integer. This solution dosent make any sense to  me because I though a float was an int. Are there any possible solutions to this?
Thanks!

```
import yahoo_finance as yahoo

stock_Name = raw_input('Please enter the name of the stock (i.e AAPL): ')

def valuation(growth_rate, pred_share_increase):

    stockName = yahoo.Share(stock_Name)
    stock_price = stockName.get_price()
    fl = float(stock_price)
    integer = int(fl)

    pe_ratio = (growth_rate/2) + 8
    fair_price = pe_ratio * integer
    percent = integer * .3


    if integer - fair_price > percent:
       print ('Sucess')
    elif integer - fair_price < percent:
      print ('Failure')


valuation(22,34.3)
```

Comment: What type does `stockName.get_price()` return?

Comment: you don't need this to be an integer here. also, read up on floats and integers.